# Error 0x80070643 while uninstalling Python

Tags: python, windows, uninstallation

I need to uninstall Python, but every time I try to repair or uninstall it from the Control Panel or Revo Uninstaller it gives me the error: `0x80070643: Fatal error during installation.` Here's some pictures of it, as well as the output log file. I found that the error has something to do with MSI, but I'm not sure how to fix it as I'm brand new to Python. I've seen this same error when people have installed Python, but never when uninstalling it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I know it says the installation is broken but  I'm trying to uninstall it

[image: installer screenshot]

Here's the part of the log where I found the error message:

[image: log screenshot]

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341) (the log). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: 0x80070643 is probably a generic Windows installer error. Try googling it itself.

Comment: I think it is related to some windows related error

Answer (score 0):

I found a method. go to the control panel and click on python once then click on change and then do a repair. one you done it then click on uninstall and it will be uninstalled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).